# get result for table having two foreign key of same table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have two table suppose table 'friendship' with column f1,f2 and 'people' with column p_id,p_name.

firendship:=>

```
f1    f2
--------
01    10
02    11
03    12
```

People:=>

```
p_id  p_name
------------
01    Vijay
02    Ajay
03    Gaurav
10    Sunny
11    Amit
12    Sandeep
```

and i want result like this table

Result Table should be:=>

```
f1  f1_name  f2  f2_name
------------------------
01  Vijay    10   Sunny
02  Ajay     11   Amit
03  Gaurav   12   Sandeep
```

i try with Union two tables but can't found accurate result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.p_id f1, a.p_name f1_name, b.p_id f2, b.p_name f2_name FROM People a JOIN friendship f ON (f.f1 = a.p_id) JOIN People b ON (f.f2 = b.p_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can solve your problem.

```
select a.f1, c.p_name, b.f2, c.p_name
(select * from tablea) as a,// which have f1 and f2 columns
(select * from tablea) as b,
(select * from people) as c 
where a.f1=c.p_id and b.f2=c.p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Join for this

```
select f1,  p.p_name as f1_name , f2, p1.p_name f2_name
from firendship as f
inner join People as p on f.f1=p.p_id
inner join People as p1 on f.f2=p1.p_id
```